# How to reinitialise component?

Tags: angular

I have some component, that I would like to reinitialise, so that it can trigger its constructor.

I was trying to do this with flag on `*ngIf`, but it didn't reinitialized the component (investigated by adding console log to onDestroy and to constructor).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just move the code out of the constructor to a method and call the method from the constructor and from where you want to "reinitialize".

Comment: thats what I've ended up doing.